# Python error: No module named RuntimeError

Tags: python, runtime-error, arcpy

Im trying to figured out this problem. Yesterday I installed PyScripter and since then, scripts doesnt work. When I run any script (in PyScripter or IDLE) and trying to "import arcpy", it gets this error:

```
import arcpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\arcgisscripting.py", line 81, in <module>
    from RuntimeError import RuntimeError
ImportError: No module named RuntimeError
```

Have somebody any suggestion how to fix it?

Thanks to all very much!

Comment: This link may help you   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z00000008000000

Comment: Thanx, but I cant find any help there.. The file Desktop10.pth is correct.

Comment: Try search the file called arcpy.pyc in your system, if its not available any where in system then you have to reinstall this tool

Comment: I cannot find arcpy.pyc... Do I have reinstall only Python (2.6.5) or reinstal whole ArcGIS?

Comment: Try re-install arcpy first. If no luck, I'm afraid you have to re-install Python.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the module is not installed properly (or at all). To verify, do the following:

1. open a shell and start the python shell by typing `python`
   (If this doesn't display an error, check that python is added to your system path or   if it is even installed at all. But if you've used Python on said machine maybe system path issue)
2. enter the commmand `help('modules')`
3. review the list of modules that's returned to see whether `arcpy` is included
   if not, then you may have to  reinstall the module

Comment: In the list of modules, there is arcpy.. But typing whole 'python! in shell says that 'python is not defined'. How can I reinstall arcpy module?

Comment: see 1. Have you used Python on the machine before? and it worked? If not add Python to your system path.. I don't know the OS you're using so can't tell how it's done on your machine..

Comment: Now I find that  `help('arcpy')` says `problem in arcpy - <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: Python still works will since `Python` and `help('arcpy)` works. 'It could be due to the architecture of your OS. It seems you installed 64bit Python on your 64bit windows 7. Is that right?  It may help to install both 32 bit version Python and acypy and you won't face this problem.

Comment: The Python that I have is 32bit. It seem to be arcpy module somehow corrupted. Is that possible? And is some way how to reinstall module arcpy?

Comment: what version of Python do you have?

Comment: Version 2.6.5, ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: welly ArcGIS is meant for Python 2.7 so you may have to install Python 2.7 to get it work. It is actually indicated as a caution statement on the ArcGIS website.. [ArcGIS Python version](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000v00000001000000#GUID-4EC90E5F-F497-4FC0-99FB-7703ED4C8F77)

Comment: Error were somewere in ArcGIS files, maybe corrupted files. I reinstall ArcGIS and the problem is solved. Many thanks!